# List of List to Dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

I have a list of lists: [['1','Kate','Green','North'],['2','John','Blue','North'],['3','Jane','Red','NorthSouth'],['4','Lewis','Blue','East']]

I want to make a dictionary: {'1': ['Kate','Green','North'], '2':['John','Blue','North'], '3':['Jane','Red','NorthSouth'], 4:['Lewis','Blue','East']}

Currently, my code is:

```
def li2dict(li):
    final_dict = {}
    for i in range(len(li)):
        for j in range(len(li[j])):
            roster_dict[li[j][0]] = li[j][k]
    print(final_dict)
```

However, all I am getting is: {'1':'North', '2':'North', '3':'NorthSouth', '4':'East'}
Can anyone help me with this logic error?

**Edit 1:** FYI, I am not allowed to import any libraries.

**Edit 2:** I have also tried:

```
roster_dict[contents[j][0]].append(contents[j][k])
```

But I get:

```
File "test.py", line 54, in <module>
    main()
File "test.py", line 51, in main
    li2dict([listinfo])
File "test.py", line 44, in li2dict
    roster_dict[contents[j][0]].append(contents[j][k])
KeyError: '1'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using dict comprehension:

```
d = {i[0]: i[1:] for i in li}

print(d)                                                                                                                                 
{'1': ['Kate', 'Green', 'North'], '2': ['John', 'Blue', 'North'], '3': ['Jane', 'Red', 'NorthSouth'], '4': ['Lewis', 'Blue', 'East']}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your question was already answered, but here is another answer that is more similar to your format which may help you better understand the logic

```
old_list = [['1','Kate','Green','North'],['2','John','Blue','North'],['3','Jane','Red','NorthSouth'],['4','Lewis','Blue','East']]


def dict_conversion(list_variable):
    dict = {}
    for list in list_variable:
        index_position = list[0]
        list_content = list[1:]
        dict[index_position] = list_content
    print(dict)
    return dict


dict_conversion(old_list)
```